# SSL for Webserver with nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am totally not familiar with SSL and all tutorials are pretty confusing for me.

I want to ask you one thing - I have from rapidssl this two certs: intermediate.crt & web_server.crt. I had to combine

`cat intermediate.crt >> web_server.crt`

I generated server.key and server.csr

via `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr`

I tryed to use server.key and web_server.crt provided by RapidSSL and I have this error `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/server.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a private key, which is required. Either find your private key or create a new key and request a new certificate.

Read any SSL tutorial to work out the details of why this is necessary.